# legacyoutput plugin problem in version 3.4.2 with underlined text

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, rte

If i select a portion of text and try to make it underlined (using the U-Button) it works and the html looks like `<u>...Text...</u>` as expected. But when i initialize an editor with those u-tags in the content they are getting removed.

**Does anyone know a work around?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the valid_elements setting was causing tinymce to remove the u-tags. Never had this problem with exactly this setting in former versions of tinymce, but this looks somewhat better and makes sense: I updated the setting and added

```
-u,
```

This solved the problem. Here the full valid_elements setting

```
 //The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style]," +
"a[name|href|target|title]," +
"#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
"-span,hr",
```